# Guessing number in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to make a simple guessing number game in React.

The idea was: generate a random **number** in the function `generateRandom`. Then in `compare` function, add 1 to a variable(`c`), till the player guesses the number and finally show the amount of attempts that the player needed to guess it.

The problem is: when I submit the number nothing happens.  I've got to the conclusion that the problem must be in the function: `generateRandom` or  `compare`.

Here I leave the code:

**App.js:**

```
class App extends Component {  
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.generateRandom = this.generateRandom.bind(this)
    this.compare = this.compare.bind(this)
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div onSubmit={this.compare}>
        <h1>GUESSING GAME</h1>
        <p>Enter a number: 
          <input type="number" name="num" />
        </p>
        <button type="submit" value="submit">Guess</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
  
  generateRandom(v) {
    v = Math.trunc(Math.random() *10);
  }

  compare(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let v = 0;
    this.generateRandom(v);
    let c = 0;
    const n = parseInt(e.target.num.value); 
    if ( n === v) {
      c++;  
      alert("Nice, you guessed it in " + c + "attempts");
    }
    else if (n > v) {
      c++;
      alert("Nope, the number is smaller");
    }
    else if (n < v) {
      c++;
      alert("Nope, the number is bigger");
    }
  }  
}
```

Comment: <div onSubmit={this.compare}> doesn't pass the event.  Try `<div onSubmit={e => this.compare(e)}>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem a little confused about the scope of `v`.

```
// previously you were just mutating an argument without returning anything
generateRandom() {
  return Math.trunc(Math.random() *10);
}

compare(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  // use that returned value here
  let v = this.generateRandom(v);
  ...
```

Also, as another commenter mentioned, `div`s don't have an `onSubmit` event, that's just for `form`s.  So you can either wrap your html with

```
<form onSubmit={this.compare}>
  ...
</form>
```

or you can change your `button` to use an `onClick` handler

```
<button onClick={this.compare}>Guess</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Only *form* has a submit event. Change it from div to form:

```
<form onSubmit={this.compare}>
  <h1>GUESSING GAME</h1>
  <p>
    Enter a number:
    <input type="number" name="num" />
  </p>
  <button type="submit" value="submit">     
   Guess
  </button>
</form>
```